# How to Update to SET Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnX with a where clause

Tags: sql, db2, updates, ibm-data-studio

Let's say I have one table called InsuranceMember which contains all members of insurance plans and their spouses. But oh no! for spouses that have a CountryCD of 'Canada' and have a PlanCD of '99999', the MemberNum's (primary key) are all incorrect in this table!

But thankfully, there is a table called InsurancePlan, that contains spouses, and where these Spouses's MemberNum's (also primary key) are all correct!

So in this hypothetical I need a conditional update statement that sets InsuranceMember.MemberNum = InsurancePlan.MemberNum where CountryCD = 'Canada' and PlanCD = '99999'

How can I write a query to make this work and update each row.

When I've tried writing this query I always get back this error:
-811
THE RESULT OF AN EMBEDDED SELECT STATEMENT OR A SUBSELECT IN THE SET CLAUSE OF AN UPDATE STATEMENT IS A TABLE OF MORE THAN ONE ROW, OR THE RESULT OF A SUBQUERY OF A BASIC PREDICATE IS MORE THAN ONE VALUE

This is very confusing for me as a beginner in SQL, but I'm sure the situation I'm describing is something many have dealt with.

Edit: Here is an example of code I use that produces that update:

```
UPDATE PRD.InsuranceMember mem
set mem.MemberNum = ( Select pln.MemberNum
                   from PRD.InsurancePlan pln
                   where mem.MemberNum <> pln.MemberNum
                   and   mem.MoneySource = pln.MoneySource
                     )

WHERE mem.MemberNum = (SELECT pln2.MemberNum FROM PRD.InsurancePlan pln2
                     WHERE mem.ClientCd = pln2.ClientCd
                       AND mem.PLanCd = pln2.PlanCd)
AND Mem.MoneySource='3' 
AND Mem.CountryCd = 'Canada'
AND Mem.PlanCd = '99999'        
;
```

Comment: Please post the code that produces the error message.

Comment: Be careful when tagging. DB2 <> sql server.

Comment: I beleive you need a more restrictive key than just CountryCD and PlanCD. With this join, unfortunately the update wont work because all lines in insurancePlan that are canadian and PlanCD 99999 will match all lines in InsuranceMember that are canadian and PlanCD 99999

Comment: Could you please post a simplified `CREATE TABLE` statement for each of the tables in your question?

Comment: Here is an example of code that produces that error:

Comment: The error message clearly indicates the reason: one of the subselects at least returns more than one row for a row of `InsuranceMember` you are going to update. You should provide much more detailed description of your table contents, their possible data, why you use these conditions selecting from `InsurancePlan`, etc. For example, `InsurancePlan` may have 3 rows with different `MemberNum`’s and `MoneySource=‘3’`. Which one do you want to use for update?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to the end of each of your subqueries, which will inform the database that those expressions will not return multiple values.

```
UPDATE PRD.InsuranceMember mem
SET mem.MemberNum = ( SELECT pln.MemberNum
               FROM PRD.InsurancePlan pln
               WHERE mem.MemberNum <> pln.MemberNum
               AND   mem.MoneySource = pln.MoneySource
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
                 )
WHERE mem.MemberNum = (SELECT pln2.MemberNum 
               FROM PRD.InsurancePlan pln2
               WHERE mem.ClientCd = pln2.ClientCd
               AND mem.PLanCd = pln2.PlanCd
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
                 )
AND mem.MoneySource='3' 
AND mem.CountryCd = 'Canada'
AND mem.PlanCd = '99999'        
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an UPDATE of a SELECT can help in this situation as you can run just the SELECT part and ensure that the `newMemberNum` sub-select only returns one row

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT
        MemberNum
    ,   MoneySource
    ,   CountryCd
    ,   PlanCd
    ,   ( Select pln.MemberNum
           from PRD.InsurancePlan pln
           where mem.MemberNum <> pln.MemberNum
           and   mem.MoneySource = pln.MoneySource
         ) AS NewMemberNum
    FROM
        PRD.InsuranceMember mem
    )
SET MemberNum = NewMemberNum
WHERE
    MoneySource='3' 
AND CountryCd = 'Canada'
AND PlanCd = '99999'        
AND MemberNum IS DISTINCT FROM NewMemberNum
```

So you might need a MAX(pln.MemberNum) or DISTINCT some such in the sub-select to ensure that at most one row is found for each selected row in PRD.InsuranceMember